# TypeError: <tf.Tensor: shape ... > has type <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>, but expected one of: (<class 'int'>,)

Tags: python, tensorflow, eager-execution

I have been trying to run the code from [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/tfrecord#setup) on tf.data.
But I am getting this error when trying to execute it in vs code.

`TypeError: <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=bool, numpy=False> has type <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>, but expected one of: (<class 'int'>,)`

where value is of type `<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>`
This same code is working fine in google colab.

[This](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/36580) is the issue related to this error in GitHub, but I didn't find anything helpful there.

Python version: 3.8

Tensorflow: Tensorflow-gpu 2.2.0

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


def _bytes_feature(value):
    if isinstance(value, type(tf.constant(0))):
        value = value.numpy()

    return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value])) 


def _float_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=[value]))


def _int64_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))


n_observations = int(1e4)

feature0 = np.random.choice(a=[False, True], size=n_observations)

feature1 = np.random.randint(0, 5, n_observations)

strings = np.array([b'cat', b'dog', b'chicken', b'horse', b'goat'])
feature2 = np.random.choice(a=strings, size=n_observations)

feature3 = np.random.randn(n_observations)


def serialize_example(feature0, feature1, feature2, feature3):
    feature = {
        'feature0': _int64_feature(feature0),
        'feature1': _int64_feature(feature1),
        'feature2': _bytes_feature(feature2),
        'feature3': _float_feature(feature3)
    }

    example_proto = \
        tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature))

    return example_proto.SerializeToString()


features_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((feature0, feature1, 
                                                       feature2, feature3))


def tf_serialize_example(f0, f1, f2, f3):
    tf_string = tf.py_function(
        serialize_example,
        (f0, f1, f2, f3),
        tf.string
    )

    return tf.reshape(tf_string, ())


for f0, f1, f2, f3 in features_dataset.take(1):
    print(f0)
    print(f1)
    print(f2)
    print(f3)

tf_serialize_example(f0, f1, f2, f3)
```

Error:

```
2020-06-10 16:55:39.480946: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1741] Invalid argument: TypeError: <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=bool, numpy=True> has type <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>, but expected one of: (<class 'int'>,)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "c:\Users\hp\anaconda3\envs\QueryAnsweringSystem\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 241, in __call__
    return func(device, token, args)

  File "c:\Users\hp\anaconda3\envs\QueryAnsweringSystem\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 130, in __call__
    ret = self._func(*args)

  File "c:\Users\hp\anaconda3\envs\QueryAnsweringSystem\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py", line 309, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "g:/Project/Query-Answering-System/code/lab.py", line 34, in serialize_example
    'feature0': _int64_feature(feature0),

  File "g:/Project/Query-Answering-System/code/lab.py", line 17, in _int64_feature
    return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))

  File "c:\Users\hp\anaconda3\envs\QueryAnsweringSystem\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\internal\python_message.py", line 542, in init
    copy.extend(field_value)

  File "c:\Users\hp\anaconda3\envs\QueryAnsweringSystem\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\internal\containers.py", line 282, in extend
    new_values = [self._type_checker.CheckValue(elem) for elem in elem_seq_iter]

  File "c:\Users\hp\anaconda3\envs\QueryAnsweringSystem\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\internal\containers.py", line 282, in <listcomp>
    new_values = [self._type_checker.CheckValue(elem) for elem in elem_seq_iter]

  File "c:\Users\hp\anaconda3\envs\QueryAnsweringSystem\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\internal\type_checkers.py", line 171, in CheckValue
    raise TypeError(message)

TypeError: <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=bool, numpy=True> has type <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>, but expected one of: (<class 'int'>,)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "g:/Project/Query-Answering-System/code/lab.py", line 66, in <module>
    tf_serialize_example(f0, f1, f2, f3)
  File "g:/Project/Query-Answering-System/code/lab.py", line 51, in tf_serialize_example      
    tf_string = tf.py_function(
  File "c:\Users\hp\anaconda3\envs\QueryAnsweringSystem\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 454, in eager_py_func
    return _internal_py_func(
  File "c:\Users\hp\anaconda3\envs\QueryAnsweringSystem\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 336, in _internal_py_func
    result = gen_script_ops.eager_py_func(
  File "c:\Users\hp\anaconda3\envs\QueryAnsweringSystem\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_script_ops.py", line 56, in eager_py_func
    _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
  File "c:\Users\hp\anaconda3\envs\QueryAnsweringSystem\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 6653, in raise_from_not_ok_status
    six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: TypeError: <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=bool, numpy=True> has type <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>, but expected one of: (<class 'int'>,)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "c:\Users\hp\anaconda3\envs\QueryAnsweringSystem\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 241, in __call__
    return func(device, token, args)

  File "c:\Users\hp\anaconda3\envs\QueryAnsweringSystem\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 130, in __call__
    ret = self._func(*args)

  File "c:\Users\hp\anaconda3\envs\QueryAnsweringSystem\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py", line 309, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "g:/Project/Query-Answering-System/code/lab.py", line 34, in serialize_example
    'feature0': _int64_feature(feature0),

  File "g:/Project/Query-Answering-System/code/lab.py", line 17, in _int64_feature
    return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))

  File "c:\Users\hp\anaconda3\envs\QueryAnsweringSystem\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\internal\python_message.py", line 542, in init
    copy.extend(field_value)

  File "c:\Users\hp\anaconda3\envs\QueryAnsweringSystem\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\internal\containers.py", line 282, in extend
    new_values = [self._type_checker.CheckValue(elem) for elem in elem_seq_iter]

  File "c:\Users\hp\anaconda3\envs\QueryAnsweringSystem\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\internal\containers.py", line 282, in <listcomp>
    new_values = [self._type_checker.CheckValue(elem) for elem in elem_seq_iter]

  File "c:\Users\hp\anaconda3\envs\QueryAnsweringSystem\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\internal\type_checkers.py", line 171, in CheckValue
    raise TypeError(message)

TypeError: <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=bool, numpy=True> has type <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>, but expected one of: (<class 'int'>,)

 [Op:EagerPyFunc]
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure much, but Im able to fix this issue with some of the type casting changes:

```
def serialize_example(feature0, feature1, feature2, feature3):
feature = {
    'feature0': _int64_feature(bool(feature0)),
    'feature1': _int64_feature(float(feature1)),
    'feature2': _bytes_feature(feature2),
    'feature3': _float_feature(feature3)
}

example_proto = \
    tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature))

return example_proto.SerializeToString()
```